# How to set form action for returning success

Tags: jsp, bootstrap-4

I got a bootstrap template and where I have this form in html.

the action is set to contact.php, but I changed that to sendMail.jsp.

```
<form action="sendMail.jsp" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                  <div class="validate"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                  <div class="validate"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-5">
                <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                <div class="error-message"></div>
                <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
            </form>
```

While I clicked on "Send Message" button, it is showing the loading word as expected.

[image]

But when once the mail is sent, it is showing the error part instead of "sent-message" div tag.
How to fix this?

[image]

Bootstrap template: [link](https://bootstrapmade.com/mentor-free-education-bootstrap-theme/)

I used the free version of template, so submit work is not available and I replaced the action with sendMail.jsp. The button is in contact tab.

### sendMail.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*"%>
<%! 

public synchronized static boolean sendMail(String userName,String passWord,String host,String port,String starttls,String auth,boolean debug,String socketFactoryClass,String fallback,String[] to,String[] cc,String[] bcc,String subject,String text){
                Properties props = new Properties();
                //Properties props=System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", userName);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
                if(!"".equals(port))
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
                if(!"".equals(starttls))
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",starttls);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
                if(debug){
                props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
                }else{
                props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "false");         
                }
                if(!"".equals(port))
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
                if(!"".equals(socketFactoryClass))
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",socketFactoryClass);
                if(!"".equals(fallback))
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", fallback);

        try
        {
                        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(debug);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setText(text);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
                        for(int i=0;i<to.length;i++){
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to[i]));
                        }
                        for(int i=0;i<cc.length;i++){
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc[i]));
                        }
                        for(int i=0;i<bcc.length;i++){
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(bcc[i]));
                        }
            msg.saveChanges();
                        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                        transport.connect(host, userName, passWord);
                        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                        transport.close();
                        return true;
        }
        catch (Exception mex)
        {
            mex.printStackTrace();
                        return false;
        }
        }


%>
<%
    String[] to={"to1@gmail.com"};
    String[] cc={"cc1@yahoo.com"};
    String[] bcc={"bcc1@yahoo.com"};
    
    String message =  "Message from: "+request.getParameter("name")+"\n"+"Message sender: "+request.getParameter("email")+"\n"+"Message: "+request.getParameter("message");
    String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    System.out.println(message);
    System.out.println(subject);
    
    sendMail("sender@gmail.com","password","smtp.gmail.com","465","true","true",true,"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory","false",to,cc,bcc,subject,message);
    
%>
```

js file for validation.

```
/**
* PHP Email Form Validation - v2.0
* URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/php-email-form/
* Author: BootstrapMade.com
*/
!(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $('form.php-email-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;

    f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs
     
      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'checked':
            if (! i.is(':checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validate').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    f.children('textarea').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validate').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    if (ferror) return false;

    var this_form = $(this);
    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    if( ! action ) {
      this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
      this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html('The form action property is not set!');
      return false;
    }
    
    this_form.find('.sent-message').slideUp();
    this_form.find('.error-message').slideUp();
    this_form.find('.loading').slideDown();

    if ( $(this).data('recaptcha-site-key') ) {
      var recaptcha_site_key = $(this).data('recaptcha-site-key');
      grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute(recaptcha_site_key, {action: 'php_email_form_submit'}).then(function(token) {
          php_email_form_submit(this_form,action,this_form.serialize() + '&recaptcha-response=' + token);
        });
      });
    } else {
      php_email_form_submit(this_form,action,this_form.serialize());
    }
    
    return true;
  });

  function php_email_form_submit(this_form, action, data) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: action,
      data: data,
      timeout: 40000
    }).done( function(msg){
      if (msg == 'OK') {
        this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
        this_form.find('.sent-message').slideDown();
        this_form.find("input:not(input[type=submit]), textarea").val('');
      } else {
        this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
        if(!msg) {
          msg = 'Form submission failed and no error message returned from: ' + action + '<br>';
        }
        this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html(msg);
      }
    }).fail( function(data){
      console.log(data);
      var error_msg = "Form submission failed!<br>";
      if(data.statusText || data.status) {
        error_msg += 'Status:';
        if(data.statusText) {
          error_msg += ' ' + data.statusText;
        }
        if(data.status) {
          error_msg += ' ' + data.status;
        }
        error_msg += '<br>';
      }
      if(data.responseText) {
        error_msg += data.responseText;
      }
      this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
      this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html(error_msg);
    });
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: How does loading get triggered ? Are you using ajax ? Also, what does `sendMail.jsp` page do .?

Comment: sendmail.jsp just collects the details entered and sends email.The details I will add there int he question now

Comment: Okay so mail is sended successfully or not ? Also, on click of your submit buttton the page will get redirect to `sendMail.jsp` has form action has that page . Are you sure there is no more code included only form is used like above?

Comment: @Swati, no issue with functionality, I am getting the mails, only problem with return status. Please let me know how to show the success message instead of failure eveytime.

Comment: Today,I tried to replace form action with google forms instead of email, now my data is saved correctly in the google forms but return status showing as error only.Same issue there also. How to fix that

Comment: how above using request.setAttribute(. and then displaying message using el ? Also update your question which is reponsible for error message showing i.e : jquery ?

Comment: What you want me to update?

Comment: Your jquery code which is use to show error etc..

Comment: can you check that added to the above code

Comment: here ajax is  use and you are not returning anything from backend that's the reason its going to error part .Because here `msg` is null . You can return `out.prinltn("OK")` or `response.getWriter().write("OK");`    from backend to frontend so that it will go inside `if (msg == 'OK') {....` this statement